# How can I make an incredibly simple node.js server which itself makes an HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous, npm, async-await

I have found very simple code that creates a server and displays a string, using the "http" module.
eg. from https://garywoodfine.com/simple-lightweight-nodejs-webserver/:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var body = 'Amazing lightweight webserver using node.js\n';
    var content_length = body.length;
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': content_length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
 
    res.end(body);
});
server.listen(3939);
console.log('Server is running on port 3939');
```

I have found very simple code that gets data over HTTP, using the "got" module.
eg. from https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode:

```
const got = require('got');

(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await got('https://www.nodesource.com/');
        console.log(response.body);
        //=> '<!doctype html> ...'
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response.body);
        //=> 'Internal server error ...'
    }
})();
```

However I am failing to integrate the two to create a server that, when visited, makes the HTTP call and returns the result.  I essentially just want to replace the `var body = 'Amazing lightweight webserver using node.js\n';` line from the Gary Woodfine example with the output of the Nodesource example.

I'm not particularly looking for comments or questions as to why I would want to make something that does this, I'm trying to understand fundamentally why I can't just do what feels like a very simple and natural thing to do: return content based on a server side request to another web service.  I get the impression that the issue is to do with the asynchronous paradigm and obviously I understand the performance improvements it offers, I'm failing to understand how you structure something that works for this simple usecase.

Comment: If you simply copy that code in your second example, and paste it inside your request handler from the first example, you'll be 99% of the way there.  Then, instead of `console.log(response.body)`, you would use `res.end(response.body)`.  (Of course, you'll want to get read of the content length header unless you know what the length is, or want to relay that from the other response as well.)

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you very much for your help, this is now unblocked.  What was tripping me up was that the response coded needed to be nested inside the `await`, which is very much the sort of thing I wasn't grasping with the async.

I will add my integration of the code as an answer with credit to you, and will delete that if you would prefer to change your comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad) for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188589/how-can-i-make-an-incredibly-simple-node-js-server-which-itself-makes-an-http-re#comment113506707_64188589), I now have code that integrates the two samples:

```
var http = require('http');
const got = require('got');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var body = (async () => {
        try {
            const response = await got('https://www.nodesource.com/');
            var body = response.body;
            var content_length = body.length;
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Length': content_length,
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            res.end(body);
            //=> '<!doctype html> ...'
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.body);
            //=> 'Internal server error ...'
        }
    })();
 });
server.listen(3939);
console.log('Server is running on port 3939');
```

This code can be stripped down further obviously, to the sort of level of simplicity I had in mind.

Where I was going wrong was by trying to handle all the `http` response code after the async block, when I needed to do it inside it.

Comment: `body` in your code sample isn't what you think it is.  It's a bit tricky, but it's actually going to be a `Promise`, created implicitly by calling an async function.  There are a couple ways to handle this.  The easiest is to just add the `async` keyword to your `function (req, res)`, and remove that extra closure entirely.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend not logging that your server is listening until it is.  The best thing to do is something like this:  `server.on('listening', () => { console.log('Listening', server.address()); })`  That way, you'll know if the `server.listen()` succeeded, and you won't have to worry about updating the port number later if you change it.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Yes, what has been called "body" on line 5 here is a hangover of integrating the two samples whereas the one on line 8 is hopefully an actual response body.  Thanks for the tips on the listener handling too.  I think I need to do an actual structured course in node.js to get a workflow set up where it's obvious what all the types involved actually are

Comment: Obviously error handling is good and HTTP headers are useful, and it could get even simpler, but this is the simplicity I had in mind at first:

`var http = require('http');
const got = require('got');

var server = http.createServer(async function (req, res) {
            const response = await got('https://example.com');
            res.end(response.body);
 });
server.listen(3939);`